# What's the difference between dcor distance correlation and scipy distance correlation?

Tags: numpy, scipy, statistics, correlation

What's the difference between the distance correlation metric used in "scipy" and that one used in "dcor" libraries? As you can see, I'm getting very different results.

```
import numpy as np
import dcor
import scipy

a = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
b = np.array([5., 2., 3., 14.])

dcor.distance_correlation(a, b) = 0.809698813475084
scipy.spatial.distance.correlation(a, b, w=None, centered=True) = 0.34003367089255565
```

Answer (score 2):

They compute different things.

[`scipy.spatial.distance.correlation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.correlation.html) computes 1 - r, where r is the sample [Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient).

[`dcor.distance_correlation`](https://dcor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions/dcor.distance_correlation.html) computes a different statistic, the [distance correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation) that was  introduced in 2005 by Gábor J. Székely.